# Conversion.VAL method - Global Hook

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net-2010

Our application is very large and we have been using VAL method a lot to ensure that data input in the textboxes is converted properly into related numbers. However, now we ran into few issues. For example, if someone writes 25,500, the VAL function will return 25 instead of 25500. Seems like it is expected behavior as VAL method stops proceeding once it find nonconvertible character like comma.

I would like to know if there is a way to have a global hook for this method I can create in my application, so that whenever I call a VAL method from my application, it should call my defined method, instead of calling from the Microsoft.Visualbasic namespace.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

With a textbox a button and a label on the form this seems to do the trick.
Make a convert sub and call it.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result, middle As String
    Dim newresult As Double
    If TextBox1.Text Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Empty TextBox!")
    End If
    result = (TextBox1.Text)

    middle = result.Replace(",", String.Empty)

    newresult = Val(middle)
    Label1.Text = newresult.ToString
    TextBox1.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hopefully this helps. newresult is preserved as a double for further use, and the value is displayed only for clarity in this example

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but this is NOT I am looking for. I need some global override so that whenever I call a VAL method, anywhere in the application, it should call my user defined method. I know replacing the comma or such other values (like $ sign) will bring me correct result, but I have used literally thousand of thousand times, so it is not possible to replace these all. Only possible solution I can see is a global hook to a method.